# Alert mechanism for auto increment columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to start a alert mechanism for auto increment columns mysql.

whenever auto increment column exceeded can i get the alert?

Comment: You can write a trigger...

Comment: For a `bigint unsigned`, the max value is `18446744073709551615` equal to `pow(2,64)-1`. Even if your app and server is capable of generating `100K` auto incremented values per *second*, then it would take long time to reach max value. In that case, is it that necessary to monitor for a max value?